# phpMyAdmin logs out when selecting database

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue with pma whereby after logging in (as root or the database owner), and trying to switch to a certain database, I am automatically logged out. I cannot do any actions on the database and in the page that loads immediately before I'm logged out I note that I can't see any tables in the database. The database is accessible by the cli mysql program and all records are still present.

To clarify:

*Literally login works fine, I can browse ALL databases except the one of my projects. Trying to use that database causes the phpMyAdmin session to end.*

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing it is down to the php session. Try a different browser, or flush your cache.

Comment: Which cache are you referring to? I have rebooted the server to no avail, as well as try different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the question is rather vague as apparently if PMA gets the message from MySQL the server has gone away, it logs you out, so the symptoms here aren't great.

I managed to realise that just before it logged out it actually did redirect to attempt to view the database. At which point I see an `#2002 error, MySQL server went away`.

So I checked the syslog for output from MySQL and noted that the 'data dictionaries for InnoDB and MySQL were out of sync' for a certain table. I used the CLI tool to drop this table (in my testing environment it wasn't a big deal). Now I can manipulate the database with PMA as expected.

The issue was probably caused due to ungraceful shutdowns.